# Expression showing date field Red SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

What expression do I need to get a date field(DateAdded) to turn red 3 days after "today"? (ex: Today is 3/13. The field would turn red on 3/16 and stay red)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need. Assuming *stay red* is keep it red if the difference is 3 days or more.

```
=IIF(Datediff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!YourField.Value,Today)>=3,"Red","Transparent")
```

`DateDiff` function returns the difference between two dates in terms of a specific interval of time.

Comment: Oh my it's you! You helped me a year ago! Yes!! This is it. You gave me a similar expression to this and I was on the right track, I just didn't have the formatting down with the datediff and dateinterval. Thank you so much for you help again.